# How can i slow my molecular vibration so objects can pass through me without injury

Tags: vibrations

The goverment has already developed it combined with a light refraction suit

Comment: Please provide more details like what government and any background links?

Comment: I don't think it's "molecular vibration" that prevents objects from passing through each other.

Comment: Now they know that you know.

Answer (score 1):

As puppersock pointed out, it is not molecular vibrations what prevents objects from passing through each other, you got Coulomb forces for that. And there's no such device as the one you describe.